# How to specify additional tokens for tokenizator?

Tags: python, nlp, token, tokenize, gensim

I want to tokenize text with `gensim.utils.tokenize()`. And I want to add some phrases that would be recognized as single tokens, for example: `'New York', 'Long Island'`.

Is it possible with gensim? If not, what other libraries is it possible to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution with `nltk`:

```
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.mwe.MWETokenizer([('hors', "d'oeuvre")], separator=' ')
tokenizer.tokenize("An hors d'oeuvre tonight, sir?".split())

['An', "hors d'oeuvre", 'tonight,', 'sir?']
```